# Spell checker on UIAlertView

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to have a spell checker on a basic `UIAlertView` such as:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"title" message:@"alert text" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the spell checker? What text will it check to see it is correct - the alert message text itself, or something else?

Comment: The alert is an input alert - UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput -  allowing you to input text.

Comment: Sorry, missed that - my apologies.